# Matlab is now running super slow

Tags: matlab, activex

Matlab(R2017b) is now running super slow:

- In bootup eats up 1gig of ram and 60% cpu and displays tons of missing paths
- And just adding 2 numbers:  4+4  takes 5 minutes to get the answer and eats up 1gig of memory and 30% of CPU.

Some of the Missing paths that show to the command prompt on bootup:

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
Data\CertificateRevocation\5769\_metadata 
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
Data\Default\blob_storage\62727b8d-e164-4cc6-8045-19f965ce749e 
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\SafetyTips\500\_metadata 
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\TargetedContentCache\v3\346481 
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\TargetedContentCache\v3\353698 
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\TargetedContentCache\v3\88000161 
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
```

Note that the problem seems to have a likely chance to repeat when I run a script using ActiveX programming and quit the Matlab Script in the middle of it; or after I quit the script and then Quit Matlab. Perhaps the losing of the References to the outside executables is the issue... don't know for sure.  Posted Solution from Matlab help Team below in the ANSWER section.

Answer (score 1):

From Matlab team:

```
restoredefaultpath
rehash toolboxcache
savepath
```

edit:
Note: 
Note that the problem seems to have a likely chance to repeat when I run a script using ActiveX programming and quit the Matlab Script in the middle of it; or after I quit the script and then Quit Matlab. Perhaps the losing of the References to the outside executables is the issue... don't know for sure.

Comment: If you're going to post a self-answered question then adding more details and explanation greatly improves the quality of the resource you're providing for others with the same issue!

Comment: @Wolfie a bit redundant because the question isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow - it has nothing to do with using MATLAB for programming, so if anything is a question that belongs on SuperUser

Comment: @Will I think you're wrong, it is a MATLAB issue, which is a programming tool. It's perhaps borderline, but I wouldn't vote to close it.

Comment: @Wolfie added more